# Cannot find meteor module 'webapp'

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Trying to set the rawConnectHandlers property, I get an error message. The code is the following:

```
import {WebApp} from 'meteor/webapp';

WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  return next();
});
```

Although I have installed the meteor package [webapp](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html) and it is listed in meteors packages file (webapp@1.3.11). I am getting the message "Cannot find module 'meteor/webapp'"

The file is called main.ts and is located directly in meteors server directory. Of course I have tried to restart the application after installing the webapp module via 'meteor add webapp' and also 'meteor add webapp@1.3.11'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it should work. did u try it in a fresh project?

Answer (score 1):

webapp is usually part of the meteor base and is already installed when meteor create is called. 
did you try the below as in the meteor docs, there is no 'raw' its only connectHandlers.

```
    WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/hello", function(req, res, next) {
     res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     return next();
    });
```

Please see this link
https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html

Comment: Thank you. Now I have removed the manually added webapp packages (meteor and npm) and changed the statement as proposed in the documentation linked, but the error message "Cannot find name 'WebApp' comes anyway. I have also executed 'meteor update meteor-base' which contains the webapp package. I started my project from the meteor-angular2.0-socially tutorial. Afterwards I had removed some packages for performance reasons, but as far as I know no core packages. The meteor-base package is still listed in the packages file. Maybe I can rerun something like "meteor create"?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using Typescript (as I do), however Meteor Webapp doesn't have Typings yet ready (hope soon), only basic module Meteor, which you can find here https://atmospherejs.com/barbatus/typescript.

That doesn't mean that you can't use it, however you will see warnings. You can remove this warnings by declare the WebApp variable in a global scope:

```
declare let WebApp: any;
```

If you will find new Typings for Meteor, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Is it preset in your `node_modules` directory?

If so, did you include it in your `systemjs.config.js`?

Comment: There was no webapp directory in my node_modules directory. But I expected this is not nesseccary as I thought I have to install the meteor package and not the npm package. I have just tried to install webapp via 'npm install webapp' and there was a npm package installed, but the error still appears.

Comment: Which config file do you mean? I can't find any config javascript file so called

Comment: I was talking about the `meteor` package, if you say it is present in your `node_modules` then this is covered. what are you using as your module-loader? systemjs/webpack/etc..?

Comment: I have to admit that I was not familiar with npm and meteor until now. As Vinay proposed, I have uninstalled the webapp packages as it should be included into the package "meteor-base". In fact I understand that the issue has nothing to do with the node_modules package at all, right? Doesn't meteor provide it's own module loader?